# JavaScript: arguments leak var array.slice.call?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, arguments

In this post [Optimization Killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers), the following codes are mentioned to `argument leak`.

```
function leaksArguments2() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
}
```

However, I cannot understand that why arguments can leak through `Array.slice`?

Comment: How is the function called?

Comment: The term "leak" isn't being used in the sense of a memory leak but in the sense that a reference to *arguments* is passed to another function so an arguments object must (or at least is very likely to) be created that otherwise need not.

Comment: It's not memory leak. It breaks the JavaScript engine's optimization strategy.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/arguments-leaking

Comment: @dandavis just add a [new test case](http://jsperf.com/arguments-leaking/3) for fun and seems there's a faster third way with `Array.apply(null, arguments)`, does the result proves that this way prevents `arguments leaking`?

Comment: @nevermind: the problem with that is when you pass just a number, say 5, to a function that uses that code, you're saying `Array(5)`, which returns `[,,,,]` instead of `[5]`... aside from that, it's probably marginally faster.

Comment: @dandavis yep, so I've came up with something like `arguments.length == 1?[arguments[0]]:Array.apply(null, arguments);` to solve this problem quite later, sorry I forget to update my comment.

Answer (score 2):

`[].slice.call(arguments)` "leaks" arguments because it retains a reference to the arguments object. Leaking the arguments object kills optimization because it forces V8 to instantiate the arguments as a Javascript object instead of optimizing them into stack variables.

You should just be able to create a copy of the arguments array in a way that doesn't retain an object reference as mentioned in the original post:

```
function doesntLeakArguments() {
                    //.length is just an integer, this doesn't leak
                    //the arguments object itself
    var args = new Array(arguments.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
                //i is always valid index in the arguments object
        args[i] = arguments[i];
    }
    return args;
}
```

Comment: seems like a lot of work for a micro-optimization, how much faster is the resulting code?

Comment: It's not that much work to copy and paste a small block of code. Breaking optimization can be very expensive, but total overhead depends on how frequently the function is called and other code in the function.